# Load title/audio from json/js for music player. Getting error undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, vanilla-forums

If I add the songs for the first album at:
line 220const songs = ['OldLocal', 'AllOverAgain', 'Causes of the Causes', `Good Lord Willin and the Creeks Don’t Rise`];
it works fine for those songs but I can't figure out how to pull the songs from the json for this. PLEASE HELP.
....

```js
// JavaScript Document
var musData =[
    {
        "imageUrl": "genpx1.png",
        "artist": "Artist1",
        "name": "First Album",
        "release":"2019",
        "slist":[
            {
                "tnumbr": 1,
                "stitle":"OldLocal1",
                "slink":"OldLocal.mp3",
                "duration": "2:47"
            },
            {
                "tnumbr": 2,
                "stitle":"AllOverAgain1",                
                "slink":"AllOverAgain.mp3",
                "slyric":"",
                "duration": "4:47"
            },
            {
                "tnumbr": 3,
                "stitle":"Causes of the Causes1",
                "slink":"Causes of the Causes.mp3",
                "slyric":"",
                "duration": "2:47"
            },
            {
                "tnumbr": 4,
                "stitle":"Good Lord Willin and the Creeks Don’t Rise1",
                "slink":"Good Lord Willin and the Creeks Don’t Rise.mp3",
                "slyric":"",
                "duration": "4:47"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "genpx2.png",
        "artist": "Artist2",
        "name": "Second Album",
        "release":"20xx",
        "slist":[
            {
                "tnumbr": 1,
                "stitle":"OldLocal2",
                "slink":"OldLocal.mp3",
                "duration": "2:47"
            },
            {
                "tnumbr": 2,
                "stitle":"AllOverAgain2",                
                "slink":"AllOverAgain.mp3",
                "slyric":"",
                "duration": "4:47"
            },
            {
                "tnumbr": 3,
                "stitle":"Causes of the Causes2",
                "slink":"Causes of the Causes.mp3",
                "slyric":"",
                "duration": "2:47"
            },
            {
                "tnumbr": 4,
                "stitle":"Good Lord Willin and the Creeks Don’t Rise2",
                "slink":"Good Lord Willin and the Creeks Don’t Rise.mp3",
                "slyric":"",
                "duration": "4:47"
            },
        ]
    }
]
var lgimg=$(`  ${musData.map((cover) => {
          return `<img class="lgimg" src="images/music_imgs/covers/${cover.imageUrl}">
      `
      }).join('')
      }`)
var lgcv=$('#lgcv');
$( lgcv ).append( lgimg );
$( dots ).before( lgimg );

var info=$(` ${musData.map(( albuminfo ) =>{return `
    <div id="info">
                        <span class="name">${albuminfo.name}</span>
                        <span class="artist">${albuminfo.artist}</span>
    </div>
            `
      }).join('')       
}`)
var albtitle=$('#albtitle');
$( albtitle ).append( info );

var smimg=$(`  ${musData.map((cover) => {
          return `<img class="smimg" id="cover" style="width:75px" src="images/music_imgs/covers/${cover.imageUrl}">
      `
      }).join('')
      }`)      
var smcv=$('#smcv');
$( smcv ).append( smimg );

var songt = $(`${musData.map(function(tsong) {
    return `
        <div class="songt">
            ${tsong.slist.map(function(items){
                return`
                    <div id="title">${items.stitle}</div>
                    <audio id="audio" src="media/${items.slink}"</audio>
                    `
            }).join('')}
        </div>
        `
      }).join('')
}`);
var audioinfo=$('.audioinfo');
$( audioinfo ).append ( songt );

var albtunes = $(`${musData.map(function(tlist) {
    return `
        <div class="song-list">
            ${tlist.slist.map(function(item){
                return`
                    <div id="albtunes" class="activemus"><li>
                        <span class="numbr">${item.tnumbr}.&nbsp;</span>
                        <span class="song">${item.stitle}
                            <audio src="media/${item.slink}" id="audio"></audio></span>
                        <span class="time">${item.duration}</span>
                    </li></div>
                    `
            }).join('')}
        </div>
            `
      }).join('')
}`);
var tunes=$('#tunes');
$( tunes ).append ( albtunes );

//    <p class="footer">these ${musData.length} albums are previous releases. more releases to come. please check back soon for updates</p>

//albumsimgs, albumnames, tracks
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var lgcv = document.querySelectorAll('.lgimg');
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  var smcv = document.querySelectorAll('.smimg');
  var info = document.querySelectorAll('#info');
//  var songt = document.querySelectorAll('.songt');
  var tracks = document.querySelectorAll('.song-list');

  if (n > lgcv.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = lgcv.length}
  for (i = 0; i < lgcv.length; i++) {
      lgcv[i].style.display = "none";  
  };

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  };
  
  if (n > smcv.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = smcv.length}
  for (i = 0; i < smcv.length; i++) {
      smcv[i].style.display = "none";  
  };
  
  if (n > info.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = info.length}
  for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
      info[i].style.display = "none";  
  };
  
 // if (n > songt.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
//  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = songt.length}
//  for (i = 0; i < songt.length; i++) {
//      songt[i].style.display = "none";  
//  };

  if (n > tracks.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = tracks.length}
  for (i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
      tracks[i].style.display = "none";  
  };
 
 lgcv[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
 smcv[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 info[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 //songt[slideIndex-1].style.display = "inline-block";  
 tracks[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
};

//Hide Pause
$('#pause').hide();
const controls = document.getElementById('controls');
const tune = document.getElementById('tunes');
const activemus = document.getElementsByClassName('activemus');
const playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pause');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
const progressContainer = document.getElementById('progress-container');
const title = document.getElementById('title');
//const cover = document.getElementById('cover');

// Song titles
const songs = title

// Keep track of song
let songIndex = 0;

// Initially load song details into DOM
loadSong(songs[songIndex]);

// Update song details
function loadSong(song) {
  title.innerText = song;
  audio.src = `media/${song}.mp3`;
 // tune.src = `media/${song}.mp3`;
  //  cover.src = `images/music_imgs/covers/${song}.png`;
}
// Play song
function playSong() {
  controls.classList.add('play');
 // activemus.classList.add('tune');
  playBtn.classList.remove('play');
  playBtn.classList.add('pause');
  audio.play();
}
// Pause song
function pauseSong() {
  controls.classList.remove('play');
 // activemus.classList.remove('tune');
  playBtn.classList.add('play');
  playBtn.classList.remove('pause');
  audio.pause();
}
// Previous song
function prevSong() {
  songIndex--;
  if (songIndex < 0) {
    songIndex = songs.length - 1;
  }
  loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
  playSong();
}
// Next song
function nextSong() {
  songIndex++;
  if (songIndex > songs.length - 1) {
    songIndex = 0;
  }
  loadSong(songs[songIndex]);
  playSong();
}


// Update progress bar
function updateProgress(e) {
  const { duration, currentTime } = e.srcElement;
  const progressPercent = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
  progress.style.width = `${progressPercent}%`;
}
// Set progress bar
function setProgress(e) {
  const width = this.clientWidth;
  const clickX = e.offsetX;
  const duration = audio.duration;

  audio.currentTime = (clickX / width) * duration;
}

//get duration & currentTime for Time of song
function DurTime (e) {
    const {duration,currentTime} = e.srcElement;
    var sec;
    var sec_d;

    // define minutes currentTime
    let min = (currentTime==null)? 0:
     Math.floor(currentTime/60);
     min = min <10 ? '0'+min:min;

    // define seconds currentTime
    function get_sec (x) {
        if(Math.floor(x) >= 60){

            for (var i = 1; i<=60; i++){
                if(Math.floor(x)>=(60*i) && Math.floor(x)<(60*(i+1))) {
                    sec = Math.floor(x) - (60*i);
                    sec = sec <10 ? '0'+sec:sec;
                }
            }
        }else{
            sec = Math.floor(x);
            sec = sec <10 ? '0'+sec:sec;
         }
    } 

    get_sec (currentTime,sec);

    // change currentTime DOM
    currTime.innerHTML = min +':'+ sec;

    // define minutes duration
    let min_d = (isNaN(duration) === true)? '0':
        Math.floor(duration/60);
     min_d = min_d <10 ? '0'+min_d:min_d;


     function get_sec_d (x) {
        if(Math.floor(x) >= 60){

            for (var i = 1; i<=60; i++){
                if(Math.floor(x)>=(60*i) && Math.floor(x)<(60*(i+1))) {
                    sec_d = Math.floor(x) - (60*i);
                    sec_d = sec_d <10 ? '0'+sec_d:sec_d;
                }
            }
        }else{
            sec_d = (isNaN(duration) === true)? '0':
            Math.floor(x);
            sec_d = sec_d <10 ? '0'+sec_d:sec_d;
         }
    } 

    // define seconds duration

    get_sec_d (duration);

    // change duration DOM
    durTime.innerHTML = min_d +':'+ sec_d;

};

// Event listeners
playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const isPlaying = controls.classList.contains('play');

  if (isPlaying) {
    pauseSong();
  } else {
    playSong();
  }
});




// Change song
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSong);
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSong);

// Time/song update
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);

// Click on progress bar
progressContainer.addEventListener('click', setProgress);

// Song ends
audio.addEventListener('ended', nextSong);

// Time of song
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',DurTime);
```